# Iptables-restore сохранение

Tags: debian, iptables

Как сохранить правила iptables после перезагрузки в debian 9? П.с. файла /etc/network/interfaces нет. Использую NetworkManager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Установить пакет [iptables-persistent](https://packages.debian.org/ru/source/stretch/iptables-persistent): `apt-get install -y iptables-persistent`
2. Сохранить текущие правила iptables: `invoke-rc.d netfilter-persistent save`
3. Запустить сервис `service netfilter-persistent start`

У вас появится папка `/etc/iptables`, в которой будет хранится текущее состояние правил для `iptables` и которые будут применяться при старте системы.